# Accessing a truecrypt volume from a different computer

Tags: windows-7, encryption, truecrypt

I made a truecrypt hidden volume on my windows 7 computer. And when i plug my flash drive into my windows XP machine. and load the drive. It doesn't accept the password even though i checked the password and it was correct. So I need to know why i cant access the truecrypt volume from a different machine

Comment: Can you still access it on the original machine?

Comment: Yes I can, I can access the non hidden volume on both machines. But not the hidden one...